# Bootstrap href, refers to picture URL, and does not make a redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap template theme, with a portfolio section like such

```html
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div class="row no-gutters">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
        <a class="portfolio-box" href="img/portfolio/thumbnails/1.jpg">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="img/portfolio/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="project-category text-white-50">
              Category
            </div>
            <div class="project-name">
              My Project Name
            </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

as of now, he href in `a` class leads to a picture, but i want each to redirect to a subdomain on my page instead. If i removed the 
`<section id="portfolio">` it worked, but it messed up a lot of the css rules aswell, any tricks on how to disable this?

Comment: To make your `a` tag  to work as expected you need to use complete path of your `subdomain`, instead your are using relative path here.

Comment: Can you please add your CSS too and put it up in a jsFiddle?

Comment: if I understand you want your <a> to redirect you to an image ?

Comment: I figured out the problem, i had some jquery making the portfoli view, so removing that automatically made it back to a regular redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@baileyhaldwin,

Replacing `href="img/portfolio/thumbnails/1.jpg"` with `href="url/of/the/page"` should work, if I've understood correctly. Feel free to elaborate more on your question otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so taking out the section   porfolio will mess up 
Hi
What is the web Site ? 
The sub domain to have the link and not try to redirect from the main could be the answer 
JohnC